# Is it possible to download previous nightly builds?

Tags: rust

I have downloaded the latest Rust nightly and added this dependency to Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies.http]

git = "https://github.com/chris-morgan/rust-http.git"
```

I'm getting lots of errors for `cargo build`:

```
...
error: aborting due to 7 previous errors
...
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `regex`.
```

I guess this is because some dependencies have not been updated to the latest rust version. Is it possible to download the nightly from yesterday or the day before?

Installed versions:

```
$ rustc --version
rustc 0.13.0-nightly (c89417130 2015-01-02 21:56:13 +0000)
$ cargo --version
cargo 0.0.1-pre-nightly (1a1868b 2014-12-31 21:39:41 +0000)
```

Comment: To be a good open-source citizen, I'd recommend fixing the compilation issues in `rust-http` and submitting a pull request. You can even change your `Cargo.toml` to point to your fork with the fixes until upstream accepts the changes.

Comment: You should not use `rust-http`, as it is old and completely deprecated. Use [`hyper`](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper) instead.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you are using [rustup](https://rustup.rs/) (the currently preferred manner of installing Rust):

```
rustup install nightly-2016-06-03
```

If you want to use the standalone Rust installers, previous versions are kept. From this [Reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2p9ekl/does_anyone_archive_the_nightly/), which links to this [Rust issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/14796#issuecomment-62053531):

> They are officially hosted.
>
> ```
> wget https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/2014-12-08/rust-nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin.pkg
> wget https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/2014-12-12/rust-nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.tar.gz
> ```

If you are still using rustup**.sh** (not **.rs**), you should be able to use something like:

```
rustup.sh --channel=nightly --date=2016-06-03
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! I'll try to fix the compilation issues as soon as I've finished my hello world app :)

Comment: If you get a "not available for download" error then try an earlier date.  Today is 2020-09-02 and "rustup install nightly-2020-08-29" works.